# Как в tkinter сделать контрольные кнопки (закрытия, свёртывания и развёртывания окна) неактивными?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я пытаюсь создать своё собственное сообщение-предупреждение, поскольку есть необходимость в виджете Checkbutton. Я хочу повторить поведение, как в случае с вызовом предупреждения с помощью showwarning: чтобы контрольные кнопки родительского окна никак не реагировали на наведение на них курсора, например, чтобы их цвет не изменялся.

В случае с tkinter.messagebox.showwarning:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В случае с tkinter.Toplevel:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*На всех фотографиях курсор наводится на кнопку закрытия родительского окна.

Answer (score 0):

В теории можно попробовать переопределить событие клика на эти кнопки:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def donothing():
    pass

main = tk.Tk()
main.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',donothing)
main.mainloop()
```

С остальными сделать аналогично.